# Woocommerce update order review table in checkout

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to update the order review table after having added an addon to the cart.

I've tried using: `$( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );`
but nothing happens. None of the .js triggers in the woocommerce **checkout.js** triggers any of their functions.

Trying to debug I've added this to my js

```
$(document.body).on('update_checkout',  function () {
 alert('update_checkout');
});
```

And this is triggered but nothing from woocommerce.

I have the newest version of woocommerce.

Comment: what is update_checkout ? event?

Comment: Yeah, it is one of the events they have added. But it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @NathanDawson no, I found a way to make it work. Using jQuery('body') instead of $('body') and it works without problem. Which I find wierd.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode which means the commonly used `$` alias isn't available. You could replace all instances of `$` in your code with `jQuery` but I'd use a wrapper instead.

```
(function( $ ) {

    // place your jQuery code here...

})( jQuery );
```

Any code placed inside this block will be able to use `$` as expected.